# How do you make a list containing random letters?

Tags: python, list, random

I have this task where I have to create a list that contains random letters. I know you would have to use a 'for' loop to create it but I do not know how to make it contain random letters.

Comment: Read the documentation for the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `string` module to get a list of letters and the `random` module to pick them randomly in a list comprehension:

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10)]
['r', 'e', 'g', 'p', 'w', 'd', 'x', 'a', 'o', 'd']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this that uses the random.choice method and the string.ascii_letters method. This will make it choose randomly between 'a-z' and 'A-Z' and then you just append it to the list.

```
import random
import string
def listmaker(list, usern):  
  for x in range(usern):
    randLetter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    list.append(randLetter)
  return(list)
```